# ARM Assembly what is a top operation in ARM?

Tags: stack, arm, operation

this is my first time posting so excuse me if I'm wording my question poorly. Im taking an ARM course right now and we have the following question

"for an empty, Ascending Stack, wrtie an appropriate operation for pop, push, and top "

what is a top operation?

Answer (score 1):

The top operation is the ability to check the value sitting on top of the stack. It's the value that you would get if you called pop. This operation is more commonly called "peek", so you will find quite a bit more information by googling that term instead, such as this wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peek_(data_type_operation)